# Should a soldering iron have a grounded plug?

Tags: soldering, ground

I'm talking about the plug--not the tip so it's not a duplicate question.

I'm interested in buying the folowing soldering iron ([https://www.amazon.de/VicTsing-einstellbarer-Temperatur-Entlötpumpe-verschieden/dp/B01HTIY61E/](https://www.amazon.de/VicTsing-einstellbarer-Temperatur-Entl%C3%B6tpumpe-verschieden/dp/B01HTIY61E/)), however I noticed it's using a Europlug without ground (only 2 pins). Would that be fine or dangerous?

Thanks for the info!

Comment: Would that iron *really* cost you less than an Elenco SL-75 or its equivalent?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Would you recommmend something like this more? http://bit.ly/2eOJHBp However, less Watt and it resembles my previous soldering iron that just died (was without station).

Comment: You want to use something with temperature control, even if the dial isn't calibrated (although of course calibrated is usually better).

Comment: Not asked but: Get a soldering iron with a silicone insulated power cable. It doesn't melt when it accidentally gets in your way while soldering. Which it does. Get a heavy stand, that sheet is a joke, worth nothing. In words: nothing. Get desoldering wick, much of it. Such a spring pump most likely rips the copper from your PCB when you try to de-solder anything with it. People who likes pumps better use those with rubber balls – and a de-soldering iron especially for that purpose –, for much better control on the suction force. But take it, the wick is great and cheap. Buy tons of it.

Comment: I agree the accessories aren't good! Thanks for the info, makes it so much more clear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be dangerous to you, but it might be dangerous for static-sensitive components you will try to solder. Although the AC is isolated from soldering tip, it is not a good practice to leave the iron tip floating. Upon handling and cord movement, the tip might accumulate electric charge, and then will discharge into ESD-sensitive component during solder touch. Normal (even cordless, [like Weller WSMC1](http://www.tequipment.net/WellerWSM1C.html)) irons do have a special provisions for a lead to have the iron grounded. The iron you are considering is not listed as "ESD safe".

Comment: It's more important the tip is at the same potential as the circuit. Non-grounded soldering transformers often have a 4mm banana plug socket which you can connect to your circuit ground. And earthing, if you like.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Heat-resistant semi-conductive (and grounded) rubber mat is also highly recommended in the process.